# If sentence in Express/Node dosent return value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

**IDEA**

I have made a second table that I will store special information about a customer. The customer_Id is a foreign key to my customer table. However from my react I have a form and depending on the information in that form I need to send a different query. I have tried with a if sentence and it adds the row to the table with correct information but it doesn't set newReq to what is being returned. When I move it outside the if sentence it works fine and returns the correct info. Is there a fix to this or how can I go about doing this in a better way maybe?

````
  try {
    if (req.body.type === "allergy") {
      console.log(req.params.id)
      const newReq = await db.query('INSERT INTO specialcustomerinfo(customer_id,type,allergicto,dangerscale,priority) values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) returning *',[req.params.id, req.body.type, req.body.allergicto, req.body.dangerscale, req.body.priority]);
    }
    else if (req.body.type === "scaredof") {
      const newReq = await db.query('INSERT INTO specialcustomerinfo(customer_id,type,freight,priority) values($1,$2,$3,$4) returning *',[req.params.id, req.body.type, req.body.freight, req.body.priority]);
    }
    else if (req.body.type === "medicine") {
      const newReq = await db.query('INSERT INTO specialcustomerinfo(customer_id,type,medicineName,priority) values($1,$2,$3,$4) returning *',[req.params.id, req.body.type, req.body.medicineName, req.body.priority]);
    }
    else {
      console.log("No type match")
    }
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        bonus: newReq.rows[0],
      },
    });
  } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
})```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` and `let` are block-scoped in Javascript.  That means they can only be accessed inside the block in which they are declared.  So, all the different versions of `const newReq` you declare can only be used inside their block.  Instead, declare the variable using `let` at a higher level in the function so you can use it where you want to.

```
  try {
    let newReq;
    if (req.body.type === "allergy") {
      console.log(req.params.id)
      newReq = await db.query('INSERT INTO specialcustomerinfo(customer_id,type,allergicto,dangerscale,priority) values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) returning *',[req.params.id, req.body.type, req.body.allergicto, req.body.dangerscale, req.body.priority]);
    }
    else if (req.body.type === "scaredof") {
      newReq = await db.query('INSERT INTO specialcustomerinfo(customer_id,type,freight,priority) values($1,$2,$3,$4) returning *',[req.params.id, req.body.type, req.body.freight, req.body.priority]);
    }
    else if (req.body.type === "medicine") {
      newReq = await db.query('INSERT INTO specialcustomerinfo(customer_id,type,medicineName,priority) values($1,$2,$3,$4) returning *',[req.params.id, req.body.type, req.body.medicineName, req.body.priority]);
    }
    else {
      console.log("No type match");
      res.sendStatus(401);
      return;
    }
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        bonus: newReq.rows[0],
      },
    });
  } catch (err) { 
     console.log(err);
     res.sendStatus(500); 
  }
})
```

FYI, you also need to add a fix for when the code goes into your `else` clause because that will throw when you try to reference `newReg.rows`.  Probably, you should just send some error status in the `else` clause and then `return` which is what I show.

You also need to send an error response in your `catch` since all paths through your function need to send some sort of response.